# How to make a Menu be added to a menu location by default in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a menu for my new WordPress theme, what I want to happen is, the menu to be added to the registered menu location by default instead of having to go to the dashboard and selecting the menu that I want to make appear there.

I have looked at several tutorials and they all add the menu manually

This is the functions.php file which has the location registered.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'main-menu' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'tester' ),
        'footer-social-menu' => esc_html__( 'Social Menu', 'tester' )
));
```

And I call this using

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer-social-menu')); ?>
```

But WordPress still didn't show the menu by default in

Customizing ▸ Menus View ▸ All Locations

The Social Menu Area still says

```
---Select---
```

Can this be done?

(Note: The Menu is there, I just have to select it manually, i.e the menu area and the menu are successfully registered and working)

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124658/setting-a-default-theme-location-when-creating-a-menu

Comment: I tried this, but It did not work for whatever reason. Maybe I did this wrong but I assumed the answer was outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'footer-social-menu',
    'menu' => 'Social Menu',
    'fallback_cb' => false
    )); 
?>
```

By Adding

```
'menu' => 'Social Menu',
```

as shown when calling the created Menu